# What's the pattern behind the numbers on this D20 ring?

Tags: pattern-recognition

I have a D20 ring. It's a loop with the numbers 1-20 printed around it in what I initially thought was a random order. On closer inspection, I realized that they aren't random; but I'm having trouble discerning the underlying pattern.

[image]

Here's the number sequence:

1  6  19  14  9  4  17  12  7  2  15  20  5  10  13  18  3  8  11  16

**My work so far**

If you start counting at 19 instead of 1, then group the numbers into sets of 4 consecutive numbers, you get this:

$$
\begin{matrix}
19&14&9&4&\\
17&12&7&2&\\
15&20&5&10&\\
13&18&3&8&\\
11&16&1&6&\\
\end{matrix}
$$

Each of these sets is a residue class of 5 (that is, each set contains all the numbers in $5\pmod k$). In order of the sets, $k$ has values of $4,2,5,3,1$.

Subtracting $k$ from each set yields:

$$
\begin{matrix}
15&10&5&0&\\
15&10&5&0&\\
10&15&0&5&\\
10&15&0&5&\\
10&15&0&5&\\
\end{matrix}
$$

From here, I'm stumped. What significance does that order of $k$ have? Why are the multiples of 5 in each set not consistently organized? What might the designer's intent be for choosing this clearly-intentional sequence? Perhaps the pattern has some special significance for generating fair random numbers when the ring is spun?

Answer (score 1):

This seems linked to the knight move in chess.
Starting with $11$ and repeating the sequence gives
(with $20$ going back to $1$)

[image]

Comment: or shoe lace techniques...

Comment: To create such a ring start by placing $1$ and then the following integers alternatively $9$ and $7$ squares further until getting a 'collision' ($1$ after $10$) in which case you progress two squares and resume the $9$ and $7$ progression.

Comment: Excellent response, and well-phrased. A minor correction: after the collision, we **retreat** two squares. The sequence of advancement is `+9,+7,+9,+7,+9,+7,+9,+7,+9,**-2+7**,+9,+7...`